# Не получается переписать код в функциональном стиле

Tags: javascript, функции

Из чистого интереса, хочу реализовать вот этот императивный код в функциональном стиле:

```
const _createArrayFromGroupObject = (groupObject) => {
  if (Array.isArray(groupObject))
    return groupObject

  const array = []
  for (const groupName in groupObject) {
    array.push([groupName, createArrayFromGroupObject(groupObject[groupName])])
  }
  return array
}
```

Попытался сделать вот так, но ловлю переполнение стека и не понимаю, в чем проблема:

```
const objToArray = (groupObj) => 
  Object.keys(groupObj).reduce((arr, key) => [...arr, [key, objToArray(groupObj[key])]], [])

const createArrayFromGroupObject = (groupObj) => 
  Array.isArray(groupObj) ? groupObj : objToArray(groupObj)
```

Песочница:

```js
const objToArray = (groupObj) => 
  Object.keys(groupObj).reduce((arr, key) => [...arr, [key, objToArray(groupObj[key])]], [])

const createArrayFromGroupObject = (groupObj) => 
  Array.isArray(groupObj) ? groupObj : objToArray(groupObj)

const _createArrayFromGroupObject = (groupObject) => {
 if (Array.isArray(groupObject))
   return groupObject
  
  const array = []
  for (const groupName in groupObject) {
   array.push([groupName, createArrayFromGroupObject(groupObject[groupName])])
  }
  return array
}

const groupObject = {"teacher":{"Peter":{"20":{"married":[{"name":"Peter","profession":"teacher","age":20,"maritalStatus":"married"},{"name":"Peter","profession":"teacher","age":20,"maritalStatus":"married"}]}},"Michael":{"50":{"single":[{"name":"Michael","profession":"teacher","age":50,"maritalStatus":"single"}]}}},"scientific":{"Anna":{"20":{"married":[{"name":"Anna","profession":"scientific","age":20,"maritalStatus":"married"}],"single":[{"name":"Anna","profession":"scientific","age":20,"maritalStatus":"single"}]}},"Rose":{"50":{"married":[{"name":"Rose","profession":"scientific","age":50,"maritalStatus":"married"}]}}},"politician":{"Anna":{"50":{"married":[{"name":"Anna","profession":"politician","age":50,"maritalStatus":"married"}]}}}}

console.log(_createArrayFromGroupObject(groupObject))
/* console.log(createArrayFromGroupObject(groupObject)) */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var k1 = Object.keys("0");
console.log("k1:", k1);
k1.forEach(el => console.log("el:", Object.keys(el)));
```

Каким здесь будет условие остановки рекурсии?